# Determining if each vector element not exceeds all previous elements

Tags: r

I need to compare element `i` with all previous elements `i-1,i-2,...,` and `if i < i-1, i-2, ...` return 1, otherwise return 0.

```
data <- c(10.3,14.3,7.7,15.8,14.4,16.7,15.3,20.2,17.1,7.7,15.3,16.3,19.9,14.4,18.7,20.7)
```

The result of comparing should be the following.

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I tried to make it with

```
as.integer(cummin(data)==data)
```

and i get

```
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The first elements easy to fix. But what to do with another 1 on 10 position.

Comment: This is a pretty explicit way of doing it: `sapply(1:length(data), function(i) all(data[i] < data[1:(i-1)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
sapply(1 : length(data), FUN = function(i) all(data[i] < data[1 : (i - 1)]) * 1)

#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

A possible approach:

```
v <- rank(data,ties='first')
out <- as.integer(cummin(v)==v)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Taking care of the first element:

```
out[1] <- 0
```

Comment: nice but i think the leading `1` should be a `0`